# Can't get the location for replica 0 in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

login Hbase, I can use list command to show tables, but when I use scan command, I got "Can't get the location for replica 0" error. what's the problem, I'm a beginner for Hbase. See below:

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
Contacts
1 row(s) in 0.2370 seconds

=> ["Contacts"]
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'Contacts'
ROW                                             COLUMN+CELL

ERROR: Can't get the location for replica 0
```

Comment: Does your  zookeeper server works well?   show  your logs

Comment: how did you resolved?